# How to correctly inject ejb into the interface?

Tags: java, interface, ejb, java-ee-8

I would like to know how to inject my ejb into the interface.
I have common methods that I would like to use in different classes, but this construction does not work:

```
@Local
public interface UserCheker {
    @EJB
    FieldChecker fieldChecker;
    default UserEntity getUserById(Long id) {
        return fieldChecker.getUser( "id", id);
    }
    default Boolean isHeaderOk(String id) {
        return getUserById(Long.parseLong(id)) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that `fieldChecker` is `static`, `final`, and `public`? This won't work, and it's probably beyond the line between reuse and using interfaces for the wrong purpose. Rather create an abstract class between this interface and concrete EJB implementations.

Comment: @ernest_k, What should I do if I want to use these methods in servlets that are already inherited from HttpServlet?

Comment: Create your AbstractServlet class that extends HttpServlet, and put your shared methods there. Your servlet classes would then extend your own AbstractServlet.

Comment: Alternatively turn the interface into a class and inject intances into each servlet that needs it, e.g. like `@Inject UserChecker userChecker` and then call the methods where needed.